# Animation without jquery, slide left and right

Tags: javascript, animation, hide, show, show-hide

I am trying to slide a div to the left when I show it and slide it to the right when I hide it, but I don't want to use jQuery. Is there a way to do simple animation and support IE7 and IE8 without using a javascript library?

Here is my show/hide js:

```
function showHide() {
 var Elliot = document.getElementById('Daniel').style.display;

 if (Elliot == "block") {
  document.getElementById('Daniel').style.display = "none"; 
 } else {
  document.getElementById('Daniel').style.display = "block";
 };
};
```

HTML would look like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showHide();return false;">click me</a>

<div id="Daniel" style="display:block; width: 300px; height: 50px;">
<!-- some stuff -->
</div>
```

Comment: I would use CSS transitions and gracefully degrade to a show/hide for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: interesting variable names there

Comment: I use variable names like this to make it obvious they are variables :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a function that can get you started:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
#yea {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='yea'></div>
<input type="button" value="Capacity Chart" onclick="animateMe();" >
<script>

function animateLeft(obj, from, to){
   if(from >= to){         
       obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       return;  
   }
   else {
       var box = obj;
       box.style.marginLeft = from + "px";
       setTimeout(function(){
           animateLeft(obj, from + 1, to);
       }, 25) 
   }
}

function animateMe() {
animateLeft(document.getElementById('yea'), 100, 700);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/geh7ewLx/

Comment: Thanks, This is the kind of thing I was looking for. It does not seem to work for me in IE8 and IE7 at the moment... Your example looks like it needs an opening <body> tag.