# Sliding and unsliding div components after clicking the hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show everything</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" value="" class="css-input" id="inputName">
    <input type="button" id="mynewbutton" value="click me"/>
</div>
```

and attached javascript to that:

```
<script> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show everything";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide everything";
    }
} 
</script>
```

And that works, when I click the *Show everything* button, I see the button and input, and the text changes to *Hide everything*. The problem is that it just appears on the screen, and I would like to do the slide effect here, after clicking the text user will see the components that slides down. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `.slideToggle()` in jQuery.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var displayText = $("#displayText");

function toggle() {
  
  $("#toggleText").slideToggle("fast", "swing", function(){  // toggle with sliding animation
    
    if(displayText.text() === "Show everything"){  // toggle the anchor text after first toggle is complete
      displayText.text("Hide everything");
    } else {
      displayText.text("Show everything");
    }
    
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show everything</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" value="" class="css-input" id="inputName">
  <input type="button" id="mynewbutton" value="click me"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a possibility to change the text "Show everything" to "Hide everything" when the components are visible?

Comment: @Regent No. `div#toggleText` is an optimized jQuery selector.

Comment: @randomuser1 Checkout my updated code snippet in my answer above. You should be using a simple `if..else` in the callback function of `slideToggle`.

Comment: @Regent When you use just `#toggleText`, jQuery parses over the DOM looking for this ID. Whereas, when you do `div#toggleText`, it parses only the `div` tags looking for that ID. Hence it is faster. **EDIT: **See this: http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

Comment: @randomuser1 If you found this answer good enough, please upvote it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @RahulDesai 1. Provided link has nothing to do with _#id versus tag#id_ 2. Did you think that in your way you have to find **all divs** first, and then select one from them with specific ID, which takes much more time? 3. If you still don't believe me, [here is link](http://jsperf.com/select-element-id-vs-tag-id) with perfomance test.

Comment: @Regent Wow. I got this advice from an architect but never performed the jsperf myself. I believe sperf. Thanks for pointing that out mate. :) Answer updated.

Comment: @RahulDesai you're welcome. It is all about some milliseconds, but nevertheless. By the way, one more thing to do is to cache selected elements to avoid multiple searching: `var displayText = $("#displayText"); displayText.text()` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideToggle` of jquery.

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show everything</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" value="" class="css-input" id="inputName">
    <input type="button" id="mynewbutton" value="click me"/>
</div>

    <script> 
function toggle() {
    $("#toggleText").slideToggle(250);
} 
</script>
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/fex229bk/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, they have a handy [slide function](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) which can toggle elements with slide animations for you. If you want to do it without external libraries, you can look at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541407/animation-without-jquery-slide-left-and-right).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Try putting this jQuery code in your script tag

```
$('#displayText').('click',function(){
     $('#toggleText').toggle(2000);//2000 milliseconds for effect to finish.
});
```